# How to pass a dynamic comma separated string list to jenkins pipeline radio button input renderer?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**Problem-** 
I have a variable as follows `def var1 = ['a','b','c']` and I want to render this variable as a radio button in the jenkins pipeline Input request stage. This variable is not static and the values inside it can change with each run i.e. the variable can be initialised as `def var1 = ['q','w','e']` on the second run of the pipeline.

I am not able to display dynamic variable list as a radio button in jenkins.

**What I used**-

```
parameters: [extendedChoice(name: 'DeployTo', type: 'PT_RADIO', value: "$var1", visibleItemCount: 5, description: 'Select item')]
```

But this seems to print every item `a,b,c` or `q,w,e` in a single line instead of different radio buttons

PS- I'm fairly new to Jenkins and any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would indeed think that the type for the choice values would be `list<string>` because that is super intuitive, but for some reason it is a comma-delimited string instead:

```
String var1 = 'a, b, c'
```

and you will have the different choices displayed as desired.

Additionally, you may have had some complications by resolving the `var1` like `"$var1"` which would force an implicit cast to a string since you are interpolating. You could avoid this by using the first class expression support `value: var1`.

Comment: okay, Let me try this

Comment: Thanks it worked, I changed the variable to value: var1 as you have stated